# Reset timer with a button in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface

I am making a timer that goes backwards from 60 to 0 (seconds) in Unity. When the timer hits zero, it loads a new scene (GameOverMenu), but I am trying to make a button that loads the main scene again (GameScene) and also restarts the timer as the timer does not reset itself when reloading the scene. I get an error when adding the public void. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;


public class Timer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text textArea;
    public string levelToLoad;
    private bool stopTimer;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        stopTimer = false;
        TimerReset();
    }

    public void TimerReset()
    {
        print("RESET");
        textArea = "0:60";
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float time = 60 - Time.time;

        int minutes = Mathf.FloorToInt(time / 60f);
        int seconds = Mathf.FloorToInt(time - minutes * 60);

        string textTime = string.Format("{0:0}:{1:00}", minutes, seconds);

        if(stopTimer == false)
        {
            textArea.text = textTime;
        }

        if ( time <= 0)
        {
            textArea.text = "0:00";
            stopTimer = true;
            SceneManager.LoadScene("GameOverMenu");
        }

    }

}
```

This is the code that loads the "GameScene":

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class LoadGame : MonoBehaviour
{

    public void changeScene(string sceneName)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("GameScene");
    }

}
```

Comment: what's error ??

Comment: the error is in the line "public void TimerReset()
    {
        print("RESET");
        textArea = "0:60";
    }" and "TimerReset();"

Comment: Have any error log ?

Comment: Assets\Timer.cs(23,20): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'UnityEngine.UI.Text'

Comment: textArea.text = "0:60" <- try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

textArea.text = "0:60"; You forgot to call the property text.